# i can't remove all the windows 10 firewall rules

Tags: delphi, winapi, firewall

I can't remove all the windows 10 firewall rules there are always left some rules that can't be removed and I don't know why. How can I remove all the windows 10 firewall rules?

I'm running the application as administrator

First, I get a list of all the firewall rules and store in a list: listaReglas
then I make a loop on that list and call a function to remove the rule like this

```
listaReglas:=TlistaReglas.Create;
ListarReglasdelFireWall(listaReglas);
for i:=0 to listaReglas.TotalReglas-1 do begin
  unaRegla:= listaReglas.GetUnaRegla(i);
  if DELUnaRegla(unaRegla.name, error) then begin
     memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(i) + ' '+unaRegla.name +' removed OK')
    end else begin
     memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(i) + ' '+unaRegla.name +' ERROR removing')
  end;
end;
listaReglas.Free;
```

The function DELUnaRegla()

```
function DELUnaRegla(NombreRegla:String;var ERROR:String):boolean;
var
 fwPolicy2       : OleVariant;
 vExisteError:Boolean;
begin
 vExisteError:=False;
 try
  CoInitialize(nil);
  try
    fwPolicy2   := CreateOleObject('HNetCfg.FwPolicy2');
    fwPolicy2.Rules.Remove(NombreRegla);
  finally
  CoUninitialize;
 end;
 except
  on E:EOleException do begin
      Error:=Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]);
      vExisteError:=true;
  end;

  on E:Exception do begin
      Error:=E.Classname + ':' + E.Message;
      vExisteError:=true;
  end;
end;
result:=not(vExisteError);
end;
```

Comment: So what is the error that you get back in `ERROR: string`? You add `ERROR removing` to your memo, but never look at the string you got back.

Comment: Are you trying to delete the built-in rules?  I'm not sure that's possible.

Comment: Your `DELUnaRegla()` function is creating and destroying the `HNetCfg.FwPolicy2` object every time it is called. Bad coding when looping through a list. But more importantly, the function is calling `CoUninitialize()` before the object is actually destroyed. You need to reset your `fwPolicy2` variable to `nil` to release the object reference before then calling `CoUninitialize()`. That means wrapping the call to `fwPolicy2.Rules.Remove()` in a `try/finally` block.

Comment: i don't get any error, the except part does not execute never

Comment: yes, i'm trying to delete the built-in rules. can i do that? or i can't? i can't get any documentation from microsoft about that

Answer (score 0):

Here's a batch script that will delete all of the rules. - Resetting to default clears the rules that do not delete correctly.

```
@echo off

echo - Resetting To Default
netsh advfirewall reset >nul 2>&1

echo - Deleting Rules (In)
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=all dir=in | find /i "Rule Name:" > "%tmp%\1.txt"
for /f "tokens=3*" %%A in ('type "%tmp%\1.txt"') do (
netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule Name="%%A %%B" >nul 2>&1)

echo - Deleting Rules (Out)
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=all dir=out | find /i "Rule Name:" > "%tmp%\1.txt"
for /f "tokens=3*" %%A in ('type "%tmp%\1.txt"') do (
netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule Name="%%A %%B" >nul 2>&1)
```